# HTML multiple line of "style=-lns..." showing in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason I started to see this in my console and I don't know why:

[image: screenshot_of_html]

Here is all that is in my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>JS Sandbox: Section 2</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>JS Sandbox: Section 2</h1>
  <!-- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can maybe hide it or bring it back to the default where there is just `<html lang="en">`?

Note: I am using VSC

Comment: Is there really nothing else being loaded on the page? The JS is inactive?

Comment: yes even tried it removed completely. I am also Using VSC

Comment: It does seem quite strange, do you have a link to a site that this occurs on? Saving and opening that code doesn't result in anything like that on my end

Comment: All sites show that for me. Tried with Google, YouTube, and Yahoo. Might be a Chrome settings thing I accidentally ticked?

Comment: Maybe, or a result of a browser extension - if you have any, you can try disabling them one by one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the `--lns` properties from the HTML tag on all sites, one option is to use a userscript that runs on all sites that iterates over the style properties on the `<html>` and deletes them if they start with `--lns`:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Remove HTML lns
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

const html = document.documentElement;
const style = html.getAttribute('style');
const cleanedStyle = style
  .split(' ')
  .filter(str => !str.startsWith('--lns'))
  .join(' ');
html.setAttribute('style', cleanedStyle);
```

You'll need a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).

If this doesn't seem to work, the properties might be getting added *after* the userscript loads, in which case you can put the whole code of the userscript in a `setTimeout` (or on DOMContentLoaded), eg

```
setTimeout(() => {
  // code goes here
}, 2000);
```

so that by the time you might Inspect the DOM, it'll be clean.

*Something* is adding all those properties to the `<html>`, probably an extension - removing the properties might cause whatever added them to stop displaying properly.

You can probably figure out the cause by going through your browser extensions one-by-one and disabling them, then seeing when all the junk on the `style` attribute appears. If you can identify the cause, you can also just disable the extension, but you'll lose whatever other functionality the extension provides.

Comment: Your suggestion on extentions also worked. I had a "loom" extension that cause it, and merely disabling it removes the problem. Not really worth doing the userscript, just disabled the extention.

Comment: Not sure how this goes but do I approve your answer or you can post your previous comment as the answer and I'll approve that?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please check if you have Loom video recorder extension 
Disable it from chrome://extensions/
then come to your page and reload.
It worked for me.

Comment: Yeah it's what I did